# Does graphql server always return 500 even if its a client error?

Tags: graphql, http-status-codes, graphql-java

I ran a graphql query with wrong input parameters, but still I got 500 response code. It should have been 400 (Bad request) as per my understanding. Can anyone please throw some light on this?

Comment: GraphQL doesn't specify the details of the transport layer, just the [shape of the response](http://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-Response-Format). I'd actually expect to always get 200 back, but it's not mandatory. See also https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So how can one know if if it was a client error or server error? Actually , it is mentioned on doc: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/#graphql-errors that it returns 4xx . Got confused here.

Comment: See what information is in the errors array. Apollo is a specific implementation, that's not part of the GraphQL spec.

Comment: 400 usually means bad query/request syntax, not bad input or other error .... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/